Proof check for cases where buying per unit isn't always financially better.
There are cases where buying more just because it's per unit cheaper is not necessarily financially better.
for example, if you buy a larger quantity of some food just because it's per unit cheaper and it perishes before you consume it you would be at a loss.
does this proof sound right?
say there are two similar items (a,b)
item A goes for 1 dollar and item B goes for 2 dollars and you know you can (or will) only consume 1 item per day
Scenario 1 Financially better:
1 Item A for 1d; Expiration in 1 day
Saved: 1d
Scenario 2 Financially not better:
3 item A for 3d; Expiration in 1 day
Saved: -2d

Is the first sentence the statement to be proved? If so, the only thing you need is an example where buying the item that is cheaper per unit comes out to a greater or equal cost compared to the item that has a greater per unit cost. You do not need two examples.

In your examples you don’t mention what action you take. Did you purchase A and then consume one unit? How does A cost 4 in the second example (is the unit price still less than B) and how did you lose exactly 1 in that case?

i have edited the question; A cost 4 was a typo.

yes it is assumed that you consume 1 unit before the expiration

Your example is hard to follow.   If you are just looking for a simple illustration:  suppose that, on a hot day, one ice cream cone costs $$5$ but you can get a second for $$2$ more.  However, you can only eat one and you have no way to keep the second cold so it is sure to be wasted.  Thus, if you take the two for one deal, you waste $$2$.

I am trying to show that if an item is per unit cheaper, buying more of that unit at the cheaper price is in some cases not financially better. in your example why isnt it 3.5 dollars wasted?

Because, in taking the two for one deal, and wasting the second, you paid $$7$
for just the one, whereas you could have bought it for $$5$.

got it, thanks a lot!
